# Does a child get reward for Mitzvos performed

Tags: halacha, reward-punishment, children, deaf, shoteh-mental-incompetent

It seems non-Jews and women get reward for Mitzvot they do (even the ones they are not obligated to do)*

does this apply also to a "deaf-mute, imbecile or child"?

sources, please

*Sifra Vayikra 18,5

related
https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.31a.11
https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.38a.12
https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.87a.4
https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.3a.3

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that yes, a child receives Sechar, it's only a question of how much.

There are various sources outlined in [this Olamot article](http://olamot.net/shiur/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%9F-%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%92%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9C) (points 7-9), see there for details.

The Maharam Schick says that a Katan receives Sechar as an Eino Metzuveh Veoseh.

Rav Moshe Feinstein is unsure whether the Sechar received is as an Eino Metzuveh Veoseh or as a Metzuveh Veoseh.

Comment: @hazoriz there are a few sevaros given in the article, check it out and see if you can some up with something

Answer (score 2):

These poskim brought in an article sum up that children and even shotim (fools) can do mitzvos:

טורי אבן ראש השנה כח,א
ודאי ששוטה אינו מפוקע מכל המצוות כגוי, ואין ספק כי קיום מצוה אצלו ודאי יחשב למצוה גמורה, אלא מאחר שהוא שוטה א"כ מעשיו אינם נחשבים כלל ולכן מעשה מצוה שלו שאינו מצוה כלל, לכן הוא חייב לחזור ולאכול מצה כשחזר לשפיותו.
 ולכאורה ניתן להביא ראיה לכך ממה שכתבו הפוסקים כמו שיש איסור ספיה לקטן, יש גם איסור ספיה לשוטה, ואסור להאכילו איסור, כמבואר בשו"ת חת"ס (או"ח סי' פג) ועי' עוד בשדי חמד (מערכת ח' כלל קטו), כמו כן אנו מוצאים כי שוטה כשר לשחיטה אם גדול עומד על גבו, משא"כ גוי. ועי' בתבואות שור סי' א' ס"ק מט: "וכ"כ בתשובת מהרי"ל סי' קצו והוכיח דחרש ושוטה בני מצות נינהו ופקחים מוזהרים עליהם, וז"ל דאי הוה כבהמה יחשב שחיטתו אפילו אחרים על גביו כשחיטת גוי וקוף דפסלינן מזבחת ואכלת".

In summary Turei Even (18 century) says their actions are viable which means a Mitzva has been done, however since they do not know what they are doing there is no intention whatsoever and he needs to redo the Mitzva with intention (see [Is the mitzva of 'Shikcha' the act of forgetting, or the act of not going back to collect what was forgotten?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/90175/is-the-mitzva-of-shikcha-the-act-of-forgetting-or-the-act-of-not-going-back-t/90176#90176) where it is evident that Mitzva performed without intention do get schar)
 The Chassam Sofer and Sdei Chemed say The fact that their actions count is the reason why we can't feed them neveilos. And likewise their shechita counts when a Bar mitzva is making sure they do it properly which is not the case with a gentile.
The Maharil(15th century) says we are Chayav on mistreating them (e.g cursing hitting).

So a Mitzva can be performed by a child/Shoteh and the Sifri Devarim 24,19 says:אמור מעתה נפלה סלע מידו ומצאה עני ונתפרנס בה הרי הוא מתברך עליה i.e getting schar (reward) for a lack of intent is not unique to Shikcha (see link), it applies to other mitzvos when done without knowledge

Comment: +1 it seems to me that regarding "mistreating them" is not related

Comment: it was part of the article just to prove that they are  full Jews in every sense but lack intention to have performed Mitzvos in a way that a Person was commanded from Hashem

Comment: I don't see anything about reward or Sechar

Comment: @רבותמחשבות if you press the link as i instructed you will see this from the Sifri אמור מעתה נפלה סלע מידו ומצאה עני ונתפרנס בה הרי הוא מתברך עליה i.e getting schar is not unique to shikcha it applies to other mitzvos when done without knowledge

Comment: @user15464 sorry, I guess I missed that.  My apologies!