# May a non-Jew count the Omer?

Tags: halacha, blessing, gentiles, sefirat-ha-omer

May a non-Jew count the Omer? May he count if he is in the process of converting? If he may, does he count with a blessing or without?

Comment: Is there any reason to think counting the omer is different from any other mitzvah? Is this just a general question (or questions) about whether non-Jews can perform mitzvot (with or without a blessing) and whether being in the conversion process makes a difference to the answer?

Answer (score 6):

according to [HasidicUniversity.org](http://www.hasidicuniversity.org/index.php?page=hu_theocracy/mitzvah_profile.php?mitzvah=161) (who lists what are obligation privileges (to do mitzvot) non-Jew's are) **a non-Jew may do the mitzvah of counting the omer**
(Related Rambam [Kings 10.10](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Kings_and_Wars.10.10)
Where the Rambam says non-Jew's are alowed to do mitvot)

but **without a blessing**
(see Rambam [Blessings 11.7](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Blessings.11.7)
Where the Rambam seems to hint (at least that is how HasidicUniversity.org seems to understand him) that a non-jew should not make blessing of mitzvot)

(In this case Hasidic is from the words hasidai umot haolam)

Comment: I think O.C. discusses a similar scenario where someone becomes *Bar Mitzvah* during the Omer period. Prior to the Bar Mitzvah, he was not obligated to count. Since he began in the middle, his counting period is not considered *tamim* (complete). Therefore, from the day of his Bar Mitzvah until the end of *Sefirah* he may not make a bracha.

Comment: @DanF this seems not to related to the OP

Comment: As I had written this without knowing the details of what Ramba"m says specifically regarding the *bracha* part, I assumed that the main reason for not saying the bracha was related to the *temimut* issue which began with someone who was not obligated in the *mitzvah* at the beginning of the *Omer*. In this sense, both he Gentile and the Bar Mitzvah boy have the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not arguing with the great answer above that A Gentile can do Mitzvos*  i just want to mention about a prospective convert in an ashkenazi community should follow their custom,** and the Rema Shulchan Aruch 589:6 paskens that those who are not commanded should make a Brocho on a Mitzva hence make a Brocho on Sefiras Haomer (although those converting in a Sefaradi community should not make a Brocho like the Beis Yosef).  I have made acquaintances with a woman who was converting who told me the Dayanim told her to make a Brocho on Mitzvos, but CYLOR.

*Avoda zora 3a:
מנין שאפילו עובד כוכבים ועוסק בתורה שהוא ככהן גדול תלמוד לומר (ויקרא יח, ה) אשר יעשה אותם האדם וחי בהם כהנים לוים וישראלים לא נאמר אלא האדם הא למדת שאפילו עובד כוכבים ועוסק בתורה הרי הוא ככהן גדול אלא לומר לך שאין מקבלין עליהם שכר כמצווה ועושה אלא כמי שאינו מצווה ועושה

**Beis Yosef explaining Tur (and Rema):נקטי' כר"ת דהא נוטלות עליהם שכר מדאמר רבי יוסי בר חנינא קידושין (לא:) גדול המצווה ועושה ממי שאינו מצווה ועושה דמדקאמר גדול אלמא למי שאינו מצווה ועושה נמי יש לו שכר הלכך בכלל מצוה הן ומברכות I.e one who is not commanded can still say "Vetzivanu" because of the reward that they will get by doing the Mitzva and since the previous note proves in Gemora avoda zoro 3a From Vayikra 18,5 that any man even a gentile shall get reward by doing a Mitzva (not only Jewish people) they can be included in commanded.

Comment: Is a gentile really bound by the customs of the local Jews? By what dint?

Comment: I know that where there is a Minhag to asser something then one can't be lenient in a Minhag (See perek 4 of Pesachim) i don't think a gentile is bound by such laws as he is not Jewish yet and can do as he wants,  but  out of respect for the local community he is converting into if it is sefaradi he should not make a Brocha which is degrading their custom when they are leaning backwards to help him become Jewish. Even a Gentile should be considerate.

Comment: +1 but you did not deal with the issue that woman were made holy but non Jews were not

Comment: @hazoriz see my second note which seems to identify why they can say a Brocho in spite of Lack of Kedushas Yisroel

Comment: @user15464 I ment how can they say Asher kidishanu bimitzvosav (you seem so only be explaining the next word (that they can say vitzivanu)) (the Rambam brings both as reason why they should not, you are bringing evidence that for ashkenasim the reason does not stand, but it seems you are ignoring the first one) (maybe he can skip those 3 words)

Comment: The gemora Avoda zoro seems to answer this questionמנין שאפילו עובד כוכבים ועוסק בתורה שהוא ככהן גדול  it says he is like a Cohen Gadol who is the most sanctified of all the Jews as it says Vekidashtoin parshas emor

Comment: @user15464 the Rambam did not see this gemora?

Comment: @hazoriz The Rambam holds that you can't say Vetzivanu as it says in that Gemara in Avoda Zora says אינו מצווה ועושה about a gentile and thats how the Shulchan Aruch paskens and the Beis Yosef mentions this as well

Comment: @user15464 this again only addresses "vitzivanu", but I still do not see how you prove he can say "asher kidishanu bmisvosav"

Comment: @hazoriz it seems that the main Brocho is specifically referring the "commandment" that why it is called a Bircat hamitzva. There is no institution for a Brocho if one is uniquely " Holy"

Comment: @user15464 I do not claim there is, but the Rambam seems to have a problem with him saying "kidishanu" (שֶׁאֵינוֹ יָכוֹל לוֹמַר אֲשֶׁר קִדְּשָׁנוּ בְּמִצְוֹתָיו וְצִוָּנוּ שֶׁעֲדַיִן לֹא נִתְקַדֵּשׁ) and I do not know of anyone who argues on that except you

Comment: @hazoriz of course the Kedusha of a Yid is far greater than even a Gentile performing a Mitzva so he should wait a few seconds till after he dips in the Mikva, its like a child has to redo a Mitzva when he is an adult https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/91027/does-a-child-get-reward-for-mitzvos-performed/91040#91040

Comment: @user15464 is not Kedusha (similar to kiddushin) that is being refured to in the brocho the separation of the Jews from the rest of the nations (by the receiving of the mitzvot?)

Comment: @user15464 I guess you can claim he made them holy by giving them the 7 mitzvot (but this is not proof) (the Ramam also knew that)