# Converting in the middle of the omer

Tags: blessing, conversion-to-judaism, sefirat-ha-omer

If a non-Jew converts in the middle of the omer, would they count the omer that night with a bracha?

Comment: Highly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/91229/may-a-non-jew-count-the-omer

Answer (score 1):

From [Hilchot Sefirat Haomer](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/2382) from Rav Mordechai Eliahu

> נשאלה השאלה בענין קטן שלא היה בר חיובא בתחילת הספירה, ונעשה בר חיובא באמצע ימי הספירה, האם יכול לברך מהאמצע, או שמא כיון שבתחילה לא היה בר חיובא, הרי שחסר באותה שנה ב'תמימות', ולא יוכל לספור בברכה, או שמא אמרינן שכיון שהתחיל בקטנות בברכה, יכול להמשיך ולא חסר ב'תמימות' (אותו נדון ניתן לשאול לגבי גר שהתגייר באמצע ימי העומר).‏
>
> There is a question about a child who was still not in duty to make mitsvot at the beginning of the Sefira, and became Bar Mitsva at the middle of the Sefira. Can he bless for the Sefira at the middle, or perhaps, because he wasn't in duty to make the Mitsva at the beginning of the Sefira, his sefira cannot be for "entire" weeks " and he cannot count with a Beracha. Or perhaps he began when he was a child with Beracha, he can continue because there is not lack of "entire" weeks. (**the same question may be asked about a convert who converted at the middle of the count**)
>
> מקור דין זה בגמרא (פסחים צ"ג ע"א), ומובא ברמב"ם (פ"ה מהל' קרבן פסח ה"ז), וז"ל:) "גר שנתגייר בין פסח ראשון לפסח שני, וכן קטן שהגדיל בין שני פסחים, חייבין לעשות פסח שני, ואם שחטו עליו בראשון פטור".
>
> The source to rule this law is in Gemara Pesachim 93a, this Gemara is ruled in Rambam Hilchot Korban Pesach chapter 5 Halacha 7. A convert who converted between. Pesach and Pesach Sheni, or a child who became adult between Pesach and Pesach Sheni, we should to bring for him a Korban Pesach Sheni. But If they already counted him for the Shechita of Pesach Rishon, there is no need to bring Pesach Sheni
>
> שואל על כך הכסף משנה, והרי קטן לאו בר חיובא כלל,‏
>
> The Kesef Mishne asks, why needs he a Pesach Sheni, at the time of Pesach Rishon he was not in duty to bring a Korban Pesach.
>
> ומתרץ בשם מהר"י קורקוס שכיון שהתורה רבתה את הקטן וצירפה אותו לשחיטת קרבן פסח, הרי שיש לו זיקה לאותו החיוב.‏
>
> The Mahari Korkos answers that since the Tora says that children too eat the Pesach, this is a proof that children are destinated to the duty.
>
> ומבואר בלחם משנה, שבקרבן פסח כתוב 'איש לפי אוכלו', מכאן שמחשבים כמה יאכל אדם גדול וכמה יאכל קטן, כל אדם לפי כמות הבשר שהוא צורך - הרי שהתורה חישבה גם את הקטן למרות שאינו בר חיובא.‏
>
> The Lechem Mishne explains that regardind Korban Pesach the verse says that we need to calculate the number of persons nominated for an animal following the amount of meat that each of them eats, an adult person eats more than a child. This shows that the Tora says to calculate the amount of meat eaten by childs, despite that a child is not in duty to make the mitsva to eat Korban Pesach.
>
> ולפיכך בקרבן פסח שאני כי יש לימוד מיוחד, ואעפ"כ יש מכאן ללמוד שמעשה קטן מועיל לענין תמימות, כי בלאו הכי י"א שאין צורך בתמימות וכל לילה מצוה בפני עצמה.‏
>
> So for Pesach Sheni there is a specific learning. But despite then, we can learn from this rule that a new Bar Mitsva who began to count before the Bar Mitsva can continue to count with a Beracha, because we can add an other reason, the opinion that each day counting is an independent Mitsva.

Note, all the arguments cited in this answer seems to be not adapted for the convert, he is not destinated to be Jew by a natural way as the child is destinated to be adult. A non Jew cannot eat from the Korban Pesach. So apparently the only reason that remains is the opinion that each day count is an independent Mitsva. Tsarich Yun.